# HTML Image Mapping

Tags: html, css, image, dictionary

Is it possible to include a sort of transparent box with an Image Map? People would hover their mouse over it to display a box that could have content inside?

I thought of this earlier but wasn't sure how to do it.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is most definitely possible. I would probably try using some jQuery to get which map element is being hovered and then displaying some sort of span.

You may also be able to set an id to the specific areas and on hover set background to whatever you want. (Haven't tried this, but just a thought)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example. This highlights a box, so just edit the CSS to hide/show/position it. I've used the HTML5 "data-" element to store data that is used to identify the corresponding element in the event handler.

```
<img width="400" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/World-map.png/800px-World-map.png" usemap="#demo" border="0">

<map id="map1" name="demo">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" href="#" data-element="a" />
</map>

<div id="a">Info goes here</div>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
    border:2px solid #ff0000  
}
```

JS:

```
$('#map1 area').on('mouseover',function() {
     var target = $(this).data('element');
     $("#" + target).addClass('active');
})
$('#map1 area').on('mouseout',function() {
     var target = $(this).data('element');
     $("#" + target).removeClass('active');
})
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but would that piece of code go in between the script tag?

Comment: Yes, it certainly would.

Comment: It doesn't work for me O.o The orange square highlights and below the map image it just says "Info goes here". It doesn't toggle on/off or anything :S